# Highlight object field, get related field of that object

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with elasticsearch7 and I use highlight in a specific field of an object. My object get 3 attributes:

```
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
```

attribute1 and attribute2 are just number. But I want to search in my `attribute3` and other field (which I did), highlight the field attribute3 if my query match (which I did) but I also want the attribute1 and attribute2 to be in my highlight. Here is an example

```
PUT
 { 
   "title": "title",
   "desc": "this is a test",
   "more_info": [{ 
     "rng":     486513,
     "more" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"
   },
     {
      "rng": 145142
     "more": "What is my purpose ? To be an example. oh god"
     }
   ]
 }

GET
{
     "query": {
            'bool': {
                   'should' : { [
                          'multi_match' : {
                                'query' : 'dolor sit amet'
                                'fields' : [ 'title', 'more_info.more']
                           }
                    ]}
             }
       }
       'highlight' : {
             'fields' : {[
                     'more_info': {
                           "fragment_size" => 0,
                           "number_of_fragments" => 1,
                           "no_match_size" => 250,
                           "boundary_scanner" => "sentence"
                      }
              }]
       }
}
```

So with that my result is what I want expect in my highlight I got `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit` witch is what I want but I also want 486513 somehow somewhere

PS: Keep in mind that I'm working with Symfony so I translated from PHP, it could have some syntax error, but I do have the result that I want, I just don't know how to add the information I want.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like Elasticsearch allows you to highlight fields that didn't match. Which makes pretty much sense. 
the only solution I can think of would be to concatenate your two fields. With that you will have only one field like that :

```
 "more_info" :  "486513 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"
```

and you can keep your highlight query as it is right now.

Then you will match with your field, from here you can work with your data to separate them. Not the  best practice but trying to highlight a field that didn't match is pretty weird in the first place